# Making 2 xmlhttp.open calls in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that uses a `javascript` function below to populate List 2 when an item from the drop down List 1 is chosen. What I would like to achieve is to have List 2 and List 3 updated. The function is shown below works for both List 2 and List 3 separately but using an alert I can see that it stops after the first send if I put them together. How can I am make them both work together?

[image]

This is the Select that calls the function *checkTeacherList* which is working fine.

```
<select name="department_list" id="department_list" selected="All" onchange="checkTeacherList(this.value, '<?php echo $user_login;?>');" >
```

Th eJavaScript function *checkTeacherList*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTeacherList(departmentName, schoolName) 
{
var xmlhttp;

//populating List 2

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("departmentTeachers").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

var d = new Date();

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://website/getTeachers1.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+departmentName+"&nocache="+d.getSeconds(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.send();


//populating List 3

alert("Is it getting this far?"); // this alert does not get reached

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("nondepartmentTeachers").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://website/getTeachers2.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+departmentName+"&nocache="+d.getSeconds(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The alert is not called because you are calling "xmlhttp.send();" twice.
The second call yields an error.

Answer (score 1):

it is not really a good way to solve this problem. I should focus on setting up ONE AJAX connection , that the script just have to ask one connection.

The major advantage of using this method is the time required to gather all data. It will be double faster then doing it twice.

However, i am not sure if you can modify the php files.

If so, please edit it. I have noticed that both requests contains of same parameters.

in js;

```
// function to fill option
var fillOptions = function(data) {
   // use data to fill drop down boxes
   var teacher1 = data["teacher1"]; // get $teacher1 which is in 'teacher1'
   var teacher2 = data["teacher2"]; // get $teacher2 which is in 'teacher2'
}

// function to check teacher list
function checkTeacherList(departmentName, schoolName) 
{
  // create object by browser type
  var xmlhttp;
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  // for IE6, IE5
  else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  // event when request is done
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      // get data
      var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      // send to function to handle it
      fillOptions(data);
      }
  }
  // open link
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://website/getAllTeachers.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+departmentName+"&nocache="+d.getSeconds(),true);
  // send
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and in getAllTeachers.php ( a new php file, but you can wrap your two php file in one if you want)

```
$teacher1 = ... // teacher1 list
$teacher2 = ... // teacher2 list

// return with a JSON type
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// reply with json format
echo json_encode(array('teacher1' => $teacher1, 'teacher2' => $teacher2));
```

The php file will reply with data in JSON-format. In the js, you can see that the response is being handled with `JSON.parse()` function and being passed to `fillOptions(data)` function. There, you can access data submitted by php and use the same data to fill in your dropdown box.

(i don't know the response content, but

```
document.getElementById("nondepartmentTeachers").innerHTML = data["teacher2"];
```

should achieve the same result as intended )

If you want to go with your solution, you have called `.send()` function twice, which the second one will return into errors.

Comment: Can you add a little clarification. I have edited the php so that it creates the two strings $teacher1 and $teacher2 and added the echo json_encode at the end of the php file. But do I put the var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); after the xmlhttp.open line in the js? I am then not sure how this 'data' gets sent back to the relevant <id>s. Sorry - new to all this.

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate the help. I have tried and tried but I can not get this to work. I have posted where I am up to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222041/javascript-function-not-updating-lists-on-webpage-when-drop-down-item-is-picked if can face having another look