# JavaScript function not updating lists on webpage when drop down item is picked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website where I want to use a javascript function to update List 2 and List 3 when an item from List 1 is picked.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<select name="department_list" selected="All" style="min-width:80px" onchange="checkTeacherList(this.value, '<?php echo $user_login;?>');" >
... code to populate List 1
</select>
</td>

<td>
<div id="departmentTeachers"></div>
</td>

<td>
<div id="nondepartmentTeachers"></div>
</td>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTeacherList(departmentName, schoolName) 
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("departmentTeachers").innerHTML = data["teacher1"];
 document.getElementById("nondepartmentTeachers").innerHTML = data["teacher2"];
 }
}

var d = new Date();

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://website/getTeacherInfo.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+departmentName+"&nocache="+d.getSeconds(),true);

alert ("test1"); // this alert displays
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
alert ("test2"); // this alert does not display

xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
..... code that produces two strings $teacherList1 & $teacherList2 (which work correctly

// return with a JSON type
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// reply with json format
echo json_encode(array('teacher1' => $teacherList1, 'teacher2' => $teacherList2));
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE, list content cannot be simply replaced with innerHTML.

If you have an array in the server response that stored as following:

```
var options=['A','B','C','D'];
```

you can do this:

```
var deptteachers=document.getElementById('departmentTeachers');
deptteachers.innerHTML=''; //clear the list

for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
  var option=document.createElement('option');
  options.innerHTML=options[i];
  option.setAttribute('value',options[i]);
  deptteachers.appendChild(option); //add the element; this works in IE
}
```

Edited:

```
function load_select(id,objs){
  var d=document.getElementById(id);
  d.innerHTML='';

  for (var i=0;i<objs.length;i++){
        var option=document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML=objs[i];
    option.setAttribute('value',objs[i]);
    d.appendChild(option);
  }  //for
}
```

then call the function:

```
load_select('teacherList1',data);
```

You could do a data split in one function if you want to optimize the code. Make sure "data" is an array of strings.

Comment: I also noticed in your question that you are accessing xmlHTTPRequest.responseText outside of onreadystatechange callback function. Please move it inside the callback, or you'll get an error that says "the object is not ready" or something along the line.

Comment: Thanks but I am still a little confused. Does this go after the if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) line in place of the two document.getElementById lines? And also how does teacherList1 and teacherList2 fit into this? The teacherList2 is a list of options but teacherList2 is a <select> list.

Comment: Yes, the part that parses the response into an array goes into the callback, where the two g'ID lines are. My code replaces one of the lines. You get a handle to teacherList1 first. Then you can appendChild to it. Note that each child is an option _object_. Not just a string.

Comment: So I need to do this twice, once for teacherList1 and again for teacherList2?

Comment: I really appreciate the help and I am so sorry but this is confusing. 'teacherList1' is the string of options to go in the <id> "departmentTeachers"- so is load_select('teacherList1',data); right? How does this function know to send the result to "departmentTeachers"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45599/discussion-between-richard-griffiths-and-schien)